# Difference in processing cookies in wget and curl

Tags: php, cookies, post, curl, wget

These two commands output different results

```
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://www.example.com
curl -b cookies.txt http://www.example.com
```

wget works fine and outputs everything correctly, but curl outputs a custom 403 error.
The problem is that wget does not support multipart/form-data posting, but this is exactly what I need. I have to use curl for this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `wget works fine...` ... `The problem is that wget does not support...` do you mean curl doesn't support multipart?

Comment: The wget manual says: "Wget does not currently support multipart/form-data for transmitting POST data; only application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Are you sure your cookie setting does not upset the external site that you trying to make something funny?

Comment: I don't know. I am just getting the page. It works perfectly fine in wget...

Answer (score 0):

Enable the verbose options and check how the actual HTTP requests differ.

Then investigate what's different in the input file regarding the cookie(s) that differ and figure out which tool is correct.

If you're using the latest version of that tool, contact their dev team and see what they have to tell as I'm sure they'll gladly sort out bugs if it truly is one.